# MigrationStarted class not found Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer, material-design, migration

Estoy trabajando en una instalación limpia de Laravel 5.8 y al instalar creativetimofficial
/
material-dashboard-laravel me arroja esta excepción al tratar de hacer

```
php artisan migrate
```

Entonces no se donde poder encontrar el namespace que asocia la ubicación de los archivos de Laravel.

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Class 'Illuminate\Database\Events\MigrationStarted' not found

  at /home/vagrant/Codigo/opticapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:385
    381|         );
    382| 
    383|         $callback = function () use ($migration, $method) {
    384|             if (method_exists($migration, $method)) {
  > 385|                 $this->fireMigrationEvent(new MigrationStarted($migration, $method));
    386| 
    387|                 $migration->{$method}();
    388| 
    389|                 $this->fireMigrationEvent(new MigrationEnded($migration, $method));

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::Illuminate\Database\Migrations\{closure}()
      /home/vagrant/Codigo/opticapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:396

  2   Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::runMigration()
      /home/vagrant/Codigo/opticapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:197
```

Comment: el comando `php artisan make:auth` ya lo haz echo?

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentación oficial

Despues de instalar las rutas de autenticacion con `php artisan make:auth` (ya que usas laravel 5.8)

Instalas el paquete `composer require laravel-frontend-presets/material-dashboard`

Paso siguiente `php artisan ui material`

despues de que termina hay que volver a cargar laravel con `composer dump-autoload``

y por ultimo

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

Todo esto directo de su repositorio

```
https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-laravel
```